# Native libraries not being attached to the APK using android-maven-plugin

Tags: android, maven, android-maven-plugin

I am trying to build my Android app using Maven. I am using the android-maven-plugin version 3.0.2 (have tried 3.0.0 too). Everything goes fine but the .so files inside my /libs folder do not get attached. The folder structure is like this:

```
-android
--src
--assets    
--res
--libs
----armeabi
----armeabi-v7a
```

I am following the pom.xml as given in one of the [native library samples](https://github.com/jayway/maven-android-plugin-samples/tree/master/native/java-with-native-library). The APK compiles fine and almost everything runs except the part where I call a native function.

From the samples it doesn't look like anything needs to be done. I have a feeling that only one of the so files is being attached. Has anyone else run into the same problem?

Comment: If nothing helps, try to solve the problem with [build-helper:attach-artifact](http://mojo.codehaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/usage.html#Attach_additional_artifacts_to_your_project).

Comment: I am new to maven too so not really sure how to plug this in. Can you point me to an example which works with Android? That'll be super helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me with the new version of Maven android plugin. Libraries are attached to the APK as expected.